# Content doesn't adjust size to pagewrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I cannot figure out why my header and header-image won't adjust to being centred inside the pagewrapper when I resize the browser window. The "informationbox" class is resizing and adjusting, but default-img and default-heading is not.

```
.pageWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #e6d5b8;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    color: #4a3933;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
.contentbox {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  
}

.informationbox {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.default-heading {
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    color: rgb(184, 13, 50);
  
}
.default-img {
   border:1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column contentbox"> <!-- Main image and header left --> 
                <img src="https://www.lifeinnorway.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/learn-norwegian-to-fluency.jpg" class="default-img">
                <h1 class="default-heading center">Norwegian Language course</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="column contentbox"> <!--Displayed information on the right top of the page-->
                <div class="informationbox" id="schedule"> 
                    <h4> Schedule </h4>
                        <p> <strong> Please register for more information </strong> </p>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<body/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with below by typing it in heading of HTML, and it is working on all of my devices

```
  <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:100%;` in your `.default-img` class

```
.default-img {
   border:1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```